# Figuring out which page is calling a piece of JavaScript, in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP file that generates a JS file, that is being included on a number of sites. I'd like to be able to check which site the file is being included from on each request. I tried using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in PHP, but that just returns the domain that the JS file is hosted on.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: by "generates" do you mean that your js file is a php file? i mean going to script.php would display a js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was actually going the long way around... I was trying to grab the entire URL of the page including it, and then stripping everything but the hostname. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` did exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

What about `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead?

Comment: That seems to provide a link to the actual javascript file's location. :( I'm looking for the page that is including the file. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 0):

Check your server logs.

```
grep access_log insert-your-filename-here.js
```